# Error at node_modules/@types/ (Interface 'Element' cannot simultaneously extend types 'ReactElement<any>)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

**I get multiple React.js type errors in `node_module`'s during the build step:**

1. `TS2320: Interface 'Element' cannot simultaneously extend types 'ReactElement<any>' and 'ReactElement<any>'.
   Named property 'type' of types 'ReactElement<any>' and 'ReactElement<any>' are not identical.`
2. `S2320: Interface 'ElementClass' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Component<any, {}, any>' and 'Component<any, {}, any>'.
   Named property 'props' of types 'Component<any, {}, any>' and 'Component<any, {}, any>' are not identical.`
3. `TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'.`
4. `TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'a' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>'.`

At first I was thinking that the problem was related to unfixed package versions, so I found a working project using the same packages and edited my `package.json` file to use the exact version. *- Didn't help.*

Then I asked my co-worker to do it on his machine and it did work! So I tuned `node`, `npm` and `yarn` to match the same versions. *- Didn't help.*

After that I completely removed `node`, `npm`, `yarn` and re-installed them. *Though it didn't fix the problem as well.*

**My current setup is:**

- node v10.9.0
- npm v6.2.0
- yarn v1.9.4

**`package.json`:**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.7",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta",
    "commitizen": "^2.10.1",
    "commitlint": "^7.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "cz-customizable": "^5.2.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "standard-version": "^4.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.22.1",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.5.1",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  }
```

**`tsconfig.json`:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "esnext",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

**List of errors:**

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:2305:19
    TS2320: Interface 'Element' cannot simultaneously extend types 'ReactElement<any>' and 'ReactElement<any>'.
  Named property 'type' of types 'ReactElement<any>' and 'ReactElement<any>' are not identical.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:2306:19
    TS2320: Interface 'ElementClass' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Component<any, {}, any>' and 'Component<any, {}, any>'.
  Named property 'props' of types 'Component<any, {}, any>' and 'Component<any, {}, any>' are not identical.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:2312:14
    TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:2326:13
    TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'a' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago and it has nothing to do with `./node_modules/@types`. Using [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) - node version manager and complete wipeout of `node`, `npm`, `yarn` and their global packages fixed my issue.

Uninstalling Node.js and NPM takes quite [a lot of steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/3614631), that's why I recommend using an automated solution such as [`node-reinstall script`](https://github.com/brock/node-reinstall).

```
git clone git@github.com:brock/node-reinstall.git
cd node-reinstall
./node-reinstall
```

This deletes all packages and completely removes Node.js and NPM and replaces it with the Node Version Manager. If the installation was successful you'll be able to see something like this:

```
nvm --version // 0.33.11
```

If you used Homebrew to install `yarn`, then simply do `brew uninstall yarn`, otherwise `yarn` is already removed from your system.

Now you will have to take care of [`yarn` packages](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2049). 
`cd` to `~/.config/yarn/global` and remove `node_modules`, `package.json` and `yarn.lock`.

That's it, everything is removed and you are ready to install Node and NPM with `nvm`. To do so type:

```
 nvm install node
```

It will download, compile, and install the latest release of Node and NPM.
Now check everything with:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Comment: I can confirm this worked even if I had nvm earlier. There are also a lot of issues pointing out it may be due to duped `@types/react` package (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/25145) but none of the presented there solutions worked.

Comment: It's totally weird! for my case I removed the node_modules and just reinstalled it & it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when `yarn` installed different versions of `@types/react`. I installed version `17.0.2`, but some dependencies also required it and a more recent version was installed for them. The fix I found (not sure it's the right one!) was to add

```json
"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "17.0.2"
}
```

inside my root `package.json` ("root" because I'm using workspaces).

After that all the versions became consistent.

Ref: https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/manifest#resolutions

I'm using `yarn` version `4.0.2`.

---

**EDIT** I found another solution that is simpler and maybe better.

All I had to do was to add this to my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "types": []
}
```

This makes `tsc` not include all the types from all the "hoisted" packages in the root of my monorepo.

Ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types